# stop rails rendering <%= %> tags, conflicting with Backbone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

Backbone and Rails seem to be using the same templating system.

Im trying to have Backbone render the tags but Rails is getting there first and throwing this error:

```
undefined local variable or method 'user_id'
```

changing .html.erb to just .html does not change this.

Whats the best way to stop rails rendering these tags?

Answer (score 1):

Escape your erb template variables with double % symbol

```
<%%= user_id %>
```

this will render

```
<%= user_id %>
```